# Revert the EC2 security group source 0.0.0.0/0 to 172.16.0.0/16 for the protocols/ports of SSH and RDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

When someone opens 0.0.0.0/0 for the ports/protocols of SSH and RDP, 
it should automatically revert back to 172.16.0.0/16 with a Notification..

What I am trying to do here is, for SSH and RDP the SG shouldn't be opened for 0.0.0.0/0..

Even is someone does it, it should be reverted back to internal network 172.16.0.0/0 with a Notification.
Please suggest a way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the AWS Config (https://aws.amazon.com/config/) service for this. AWS Config allows you to create audit rules which will be checked. It will automatically generate SNS notification if a rules is violated, which you could use to trigger a lambda to correct the mistake (or something like that).

Rules which check for specific IP-addresses in a SG are part of the default rule options, so there's no need to create any yourself.

*Edit:* You can use auto-remediation with the 'AWS-DisablePublicAccessForSecurityGroup' remediation action. This should allow you to achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks.. That was the same I was thinking about. But I couldn't find any default rules to change the source IP Range.. Also, should revert only for SSH and RDP.

Comment: I guess you could always copy the remediation action and create a custom one. That might be the easiest option

Comment: Copy the rule and create new rule or copy and create new remediation action? RDP and SSH are my ports.. Also please suggest the rule name that is more suitable/

Comment: Yes, I tried Config and AWS-DisablePublicAccessForSecurityGroup remediation and it removed the SSH or RDP Rule if its 0.0.0.0/0. But Instead of removing, can it be changed to 172.16.0.0/0?

Comment: @mytech, Did you ever get the solution to what you were looking for? I am curious to know how it is done finally. Please share.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can modify security groups without having been given permission to do so, so the correct solution is that you don't give this permission to users who shouldn't have it.  Everything in AWS that you don't grant is denied by default.

Simply reverting an insecure configuration change like this is not sufficient, depending on timing.

Security group rules for TCP control what connections are allowed *to be initially created* -- not what connections are allowed to stand.  If...

- I change the rule to one that allows 0.0.0.0/0; then
- I establish a connection from an unintentially (to you) allowed (by me) address (e.g. 203.0.113.1); then
- you remove the rule or revert the change that allows 0.0.0.0/0

...your change does not disconnect me.  If I connected while the rule was in place, then I can remain connected from the no-longer-authorized address 203.0.113.1 until I disconnect or time out despite what your security group setting *now* say.

Be sure you are not solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Sorry, Permissions will be given in 1st place.. If someone who has the permission changes/creates to 0.0.0.0/0, it should revoke.. AWS Config does it.. It will auto remediate and will be removed in few secs.